# Change x-axis range to percent of bullet chart in NVD3

Tags: nvd3.js

Please help me how can i change x-axis range of bullet chart to percentage?

i have this code of my NVD3.js bullet chart

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.bulletChart();

    chart.tooltip.valueFormatter(function(d){
        return ''+ numberWithCommas(d)+''; //on hover show percentage and value
    });

    d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(data)
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .call(chart);

    return chart;
});

function numberWithCommas(x) {
   return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

here's my data variable

```
var data = {
   measureLabels: ["Total Obligated"]
   measures:[0]
   rangeLabels:["Available Amount"]
   ranges:[28464000]
   subtitle:"CODE"
  title:"200000100003000"
}
```

i have tried to add this code

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
        //return ranges * 100 / ranges
});
```

but it said that 'tickFormat' is not a function.

Comment: Any update on this @p3sc3

Comment: i have my own answer in the bottom,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figure out how to change it LOL!.

i added this code.

```
d3.selectAll('g.nv-tick').select('text').text(function (t) {
    return (100 * t / data.ranges[0]).toFixed();
});
```

i tooks me half a day to figure it out T_T